# Python: Best way to visualize dict of dicts

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I want to visualize the following dict of dicts

```
players_info = {'Afghanistan': {'Asghar Stanikzai': 809.0,
  'Mohammad Nabi': 851.0,
  'Mohammad Shahzad': 1713.0,
  'Najibullah Zadran': 643.0,
  'Samiullah Shenwari': 774.0},
 'Australia': {'AJ Finch': 1082.0,
  'CL White': 988.0,
  'DA Warner': 1691.0,
  'GJ Maxwell': 822.0,
  'SR Watson': 1465.0},
 'England': {'AD Hales': 1340.0,
  'EJG Morgan': 1577.0,
  'JC Buttler': 985.0,
  'KP Pietersen': 1176.0,
  'LJ Wright': 759.0}}
```

Currently I am using the following way but with large dict it is making a clutter which I don't want.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.DataFrame(players_info).plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Please suggest a better way of visualizing it. Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question depends on how you are going to use the data. Unfortunately, I fear your question is wholly opinion-based. If you tell us precisely what you wish to emphasize in your data or a specific method then you are more likely to attract helpful responses.

Comment: @jpp I am trying to plot simple bar chart to analyze the difference scores each player in each country but as I said it is making clutter so I want to know a better way than using a bar chart

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [`heatmap`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html?highlight=heatmap#seaborn.heatmap).

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize":(12,8)})

df = pd.DataFrame(players_info)
g = sns.heatmap(df, cmap="Blues", annot=True, fmt='g')
g.get_figure().savefig("heatmap.png")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Though it might not be the optimal way of presenting the results but the reason for accepting this answer that it is surely a different way then a bar plot. Any other methods would also be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You first need a better dataframe structure out of your dict.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(i,j,players_info[i][j]) for i in players_info.keys() for j in players_info[i].keys()], columns=["country", "player", "score"])
```

Then, you may use the plotting like below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
ax = sns.barplot(x="player", y="score", hue="country" ,data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]